# Problem reading twice from keyboard in NASM assembler

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, user-input, nasm

I am trying to read two values from keyboard, I want to store the values in memory. However, the behavior is not what I expect. The flow of the program should be: I ask for the first number, the user enters the number, I ask for the second number, and the user types the second number. What happens is that when asking for the second number the program ends directly without leaving room to write the value. What am I doing wrong? I think it must be something about the newline value but I am not very clear about it. I am using NASM 2.13.02 on Ubuntu.

```
%macro print 2
    MOV EAX, 4
    MOV EBX, 1
    MOV ECX, %1
    MOV EDX, %2
    INT 0x80
%endmacro

%macro read1 0
    MOV EAX, 3
    MOV EBX, 0
    MOV ECX, val1
    MOV EDX, 1
    INT 0x80

%endmacro


%macro read2 0
    MOV EAX, 3
    MOV EBX, 0
    MOV ECX, val2
    MOV EDX, 1
    INT 0x80
%endmacro

section .bss
    val1 RESB 1      ; Option
    val2 RESB 1      ; Value

section .data    
    mnc1 DB 'Type the first value: '
    len1 EQU $ - mnc1
    mnc2 DB 'Type the second value: '
    len2 EQU $ - mnc2

section .text
    imprimir mnc1, len1
    read1
    imprimir mnc2, len2
    read2
    MOV EAX, 1
    MOV EBX, 0
    INT 0x80
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Don't you want `read1` and `read2` to actually invoke `int 0x80`?

Comment: @NateEldredge Typing error while copying the code. What I was noticing and I don't know if it is true, is that I need a byte to store the line break, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, if you pressed Enter after typing the first digit, then the input stream will contain a newline character, which will be the next thing you read.  So yes, if you want to get to the next digit, you have to read the newline character, which requires having somewhere to store it.

Comment: @NateEldredge I understand, thank you.